# MacOS terminal ssh input buffer size

Tags: osx, ssh, tty

I am trying to cut-paste some switch config over an ssh session from my mac. It seems to start mangling it after a set buffer size. Surely cut-paste buffer is large enough, since I can cut-paste just fine in other programs(even chrome terminal emulator for the same ssh session funny enough). Is there a way to increase this cut-paste buffer to a terminal on MacOS, or am I stuck cut-pasting in short bursts?

**EDIT:**
So, after quite a bit of debugging of the kernel tty driver on the OS where I was connecting to, I found that the root cause of it was the specific tty implementation, which had only a small buffer (1k). As a result pasting anything larger would overrun that buffer and create the above mentioned problem. With chrome terminal emulator, it looks like it has its own buffer and just waits for a prompt and sends it line-by-line to the pty.

Comment: What happens if you use `pbpaste` to send the data over the SSH session?

Comment: It works yes, but is it really the solution? Basically that means that I have to log out from my switch and do the `pbpaste | ssh admin@switch`  every time I have to paste something.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution to increase the amount of data you can paste into an SSH session but I do have a workaround that might work for you. The workaround involves X11 forwarding and sharing the OS X clipboard with the X server pasteboard.

## Set Up X11 Forwarding

To set up X11 Forwarding on your remote server you need to edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and change the line

```
#X11Forwarding no
```

to

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

You need to **restart** the SSH daemon after you update the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Now we need to install `xauth` on your remote server with the appropriate command for your platform

```
sudo pacman -S xorg-xauth # Arch-Linux
sudo apt-get install xauth # Debian/Ubuntu/etc.
sudo yum install xauth # RHEL/CentOS/Fedora/etc.
```

You can then connect to your server using the `-X`, or -`Y` options.

- `-X` will enable X11 forwarding.
- `-Y` will enable trusted X11 forwarding.

*This step may or may not be needed depending on your version of OpenSSH.* There is a known bug in OpenSSH that results in the message

> X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

when attempting to connect to a remote server with X11 forwarding. The fix is to edit your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and change the line

```
#X11UseLocalhost yes
```

to

```
X11UseLocalhost no
```

You should now be successfully able to connect to your remote server with X11 forwarding on.

## Sharing the OS X and X Server Clipboards

To share the OS X keyboard with the X server we need to edit the file `~/Library/Preferences/org.x.X11.plist` or `~/Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist` depending on your version of OS X. You can use `ls ~/Library/Preferences/ | grep X11` to determine which file you need to edit. We need to add 5 boolean keys to this

```
sync_clipboard_to_pasteboard
sync_pasteboard
sync_pasteboard_to_clipboard
sync_pasteboard_to_primary
sync_primary_on_select
```

The easiest way to add these is probably to use terminal commands

```
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_clipboard_to_pasteboard -boolean true
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_pasteboard -boolean true
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_pasteboard_to_clipboard -boolean true
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_pasteboard_to_primary -boolean true
defaults write org.macosforge.xquartz.X11 sync_primary_on_select -boolean true
```

*replacing `org.macosforge.xquartz.X11` with `org.x.X11` if necessary*. After making this change you also need to restart the X server, logging off your SSH session and quitting the application from the dock will suffice.

There also seems to be a [bug in XQuartz](https://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/ticket/765) that ships with later versions of OS X that requires you to start `xclock` from the OS X terminal before the OS X and X server clipboards will be shared.

## Copy and Pasting

Now everything is in place to copy and paste between the OS X clipboard and the X server clipboard. The last thing to do is install `xclip` on your remote server and *copy and paste* to your hearts content.

The sequence you need to initialise copy and pasting is to first SSH to your remote server

```
$ ssh -X [user@]hostname
```

then in another terminal window run

```
$ xclock
^C
```

where `^C` stands for CTRL+C. Copy from OS X with `pbcopy` or CMD+C and paste on your remote server with `xclip`.

- `xclip -o` will print the contents of the clipboard to `stdout`, whilst
- `xclip -i` will read from `stdin` to the clipboard

Comment: Really nice detailed writeup, but doesn't really help in my case. The device I am ssh'ing to is a network device where I don't have a root access and or OS on that said device doesn't have much in terms of prebuilt packages. I just refuse to believe that Apple didn't add the ability to increase terminal input buffer somewhere in the settings I guess.

Comment: Ah well, that was the best method I could find. I don't think your issue is OS X. I think it is on the external device but seen as though you don't have access I'm not sure what else I can suggest unless you send files across with `scp` or `ftp`.